# The map $f:\mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ given by $f(x + 3\mathbb{Z}) = x + 6\mathbb{Z}$ is not well-defined

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

By naming an equivalence class in the domain that is assigned at least two different values prove that the following is not a well defined function.

> $$f : \Bbb Z_{3} \to \Bbb Z_{6} \;\;\;\text{ given by } f(\overline x) = [x]  $$
>
> In this case we represent an element of the domain as an $\bar x$ and use the notation $[x]$ for equivalence classes in the co-domain.

$f(\overline0) =  [0] \;,$  $ \Bbb Z_{3}  \quad (3x+0)\;\; \overline 0 = \{ ...-6,-3,0,3,6...  \}, \; \Bbb Z_{6}\;  (6x+0)\; \overline0 =\{ ...-12,-6,0,6,12...\}$

$f(\overline1) = [1], $ $\qquad   \; (3x+1) \; \;\;\;\overline   1 = \{ ...-5,-2,1,4,7 ... \},\; \;  (6x+1)\;\overline1 =\{...-11,-5,1,7,13.. \}$

$f(\overline2) = [2], $ $\qquad  \qquad \qquad \;\overline 2 = \{ ...-4,-3,2,5,8 ... \},\;\;\overline 2 = \{ ...-10,-4,2,8,14  ...\},\;$

$f(\overline3) = [3] ,$  $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad,\; \quad \quad \quad \; \; \; \;\overline 3 = \{ ...-9,-3,3,9,15 ... \},$

$f(\overline4) =  [4],\qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \; \quad \quad \quad \quad \; \;\overline 4 = \{ ...-8,-2,4,10,16...  \}, $

$f(\overline5) = [5], \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \; \quad \quad \quad \quad \;\;\overline 5 = \{ ...-7,-1,5,11,17...  \},  $

$f(\overline6) = [6] ,$

So my main question for this problem is how to find out if this question is not a function. From the information I have gathered here I still cannot see why this is not a function any help on showing how this is not function would be much appreciated.

> The set of equivalence classes for the relation $\cong_{m}$ is denoted $\Bbb Z_{m}$

The $ 3x+0 \text{ and } 6x+0$ are just showing how I got $\overline 0 $

Comment: My mistake an equivalence relation is the set of equivalence classes for the relation $\cong$ m is denoted $\Bbb Z_{m}$

Comment: What does $x$ range over? If $x$ can take on the values $0, 1, 2$, then this is a perfectly well-defined function. However, you won't have that $f(\overline x) = [x]$ for all $x \in {\mathbb N}$, as $f(\overline 0) = f(\overline 3)$.

Comment: What is $[x] $? The equivalence class of $x $ by equivalence mod 6, perhaps? If so then $\overline {0}$ should get mapped to $[0] $ and also to $[3] $ which are not the same.

Comment: @Ian That  I do not understand.

Comment: @Ian Why do you put 0 into your equivalence class?

Comment: @LittleJon I assume that $\overline{x}$ means "the equivalence class of $x$ mod 3" while $[x]$ means "the equivalence class of $x$ mod 6". With that in mind, notice that the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ can be identified as $\overline{0},\overline{1}$ and $\overline{2}$. For example $\overline{0}=\{ \dots,-6,-3,0,3,6,\dots \}$. Now in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, $[0]=\{ \dots,-12,-6,0,6,12,\dots \}$ while $[3]=\{ \dots,-15,-9,-3,3,9,\dots \}$. These are different elements in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ but they are in the same equivalence class in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: (Cont.) This is why your function isn't well-defined, provided that the integer variable $x$ in its definition is allowed to vary over *all* integers. As Magdiragdag said, if you constrain the possible values of $x$ then the situation can change.

Comment: @Ian Would you be referring to something like this $ 3n +0$, $n \in \Bbb Z$ =       {  $...-6,-3,0,3,6... $} ?

Comment: After so many comments it is still unclear what are $x$,  $\bar x$, and $[x]$ in your formula.

Comment: In this case we represent an element of the domain as an $\bar x$  and use the notation $[x]$ for equivalence classes in the co-domain.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and also because it can help), how do you define $\Bbb Z_3$? I assume as the quotient group/ring $\Bbb Z / 3\Bbb Z$, otherwise the notation doesn't *exactly* make sense, at least not obviously.

Comment: I edited my question as to answer your question.

Comment: What does $≅_m$ mean?

Comment: Do you mean the $\bar x$s in the right side are $[x]$s? If it is then $f$ _is_ a function.

Comment: @LittleJon My feeling is you made a mistake.

Comment: Do the bracketed sets extend infinitely both ways? Or are they finite, or are they infinite in one direction? There is so much ambiguity in your question.

Comment: @user351579 I wrote the question exactly as shown. I tried to put as much information as that someone might provide an adequate answer. I see what you mean though my answer had a mistake which I will edit. It is infinite.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Can you shove 3 pigeons into 6 holes?

Comment: @LittleJon: I've changed the title (to fix the markup in $\mathbb{Z}_6)$ and rewrote it using more standard notation (for at least the title, so that the intent is clear from just reading that in isolation); feel free to change it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @anomaly the strangest thing is that at different aspect ratios it looks different to other people I will keep it as is. (Like on a mac computer the alignment is fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show that

$\mathbb Z_3=\left\{\begin{array}\{
\{...,-6,-3,0,3,6,...\},\\
\{...,-5,-2,1,4,7,...\},\\
\{...,-4,-1,2,5,8,...\}\end{array}\right\}$

and that

$\mathbb Z_6=\left\{\begin{array}\{
\{...,-12,-6,0,6,12,...\},\\
\{...,-11,-5,1,7,13,...\},\\
\{...,-10,-4,2,8,14,...\},\\
\{...,-9,-3,3,9,15,...\},\\
\{...,-8,-2,4,10,16,...\},\\
\{...,-7,-1,5,11,17,...\}\end{array}\right\}$

, because $\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_3$ are sets of equivalence classes. Let the relation $f$ be represented by a diagram:

[image: diagram 1]

Here, the relation lines show that $f(\bar1)=[1]$, $f(\bar2)=[2]$, and $f(\bar3)=[3]$.

But consider that $\bar0\cong_3\bar3$, which means they are the same element in $\mathbb Z_3$ (Remember, $\mathbb Z_3$ is a set of equivalence classes). Then, consider that $f(\bar0)=f(\bar3)=[3]$. Putting this into the diagram yields

[image: diagram 2]

, which shows that $f$ is clearly not a function, because a function maps each element in its domain to exactly $1$ element in its co-domain. $Q.E.D.$

Answer (score 8):

If a function $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ with $f(\overline{x}) = [x]$ for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ would exist, then
$$
    [0]
  = f(\overline{0})
  = f(\overline{3})
  = [3],
$$
where we used for the second equality that $\overline{0} = \overline{3}$.
By the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ we have for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ that $[x] = [y]$ if and only if $x - y$ is divisible by $6$, i.e. if $x - y \in 6\mathbb{Z} = \{6n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
So $[0] = [3]$ is equivalent to $3 - 0 = 3$ being divisible by $6$, which doesn’t hold.

This contradiction shows that no such function $f$ exists.

More generally one can show that there exists a function $g \colon \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ with $g(\overline{x}) = [x]$ for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: Where did $x-y$ come from? What $\overline 0 = \overline 3$. Is this refering to $ \Bbb Z_{3} or \Bbb Z_{6} $? Sorry to ask I am just trying to understand everything.

Comment: So you use this formula in your answer :$ x = y(\text{mod}\; m)$ $ \Leftarrow \Rightarrow  m|(x-y)$

Comment: By writing $\overline{0} = \overline{3}$ I’m referring to the equivalence classes in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (this is the notation you’re using in your post). If you are not familiar with the fact that $[x] = [y] \iff 6|(x - y)$, then I think it would be useful to know what your definition of $\cong_6$ is.

Comment: $\cong_{6}$  You mean the equivalence class definition I wrote above.

Comment: Yes, I’m just using your notation here.

Comment: I think I understand what it means. In $\Bbb Z_{3} $ we say that $\overline 0 = \overline 3$. Which is true but for $\Bbb Z_{6}$  we cannot say                               0 = $\overline 3$. This is not true by the information above.

Comment: Thus we say $\overline 0 \neq \overline 3$ or $[0] \neq [3].$

Comment: It would be better to use clearer notation: for example, $f([0]_3)=f([0]_6)$.

Comment: why does $y = x (mod\; \;m)$ determine if it is a function or not I am not seeing that connection. because $y= xmod3 \Rightarrow$ $3|y-x $? Is it because 3 is divisible by 6?

Comment: I just trying to understand its significance of  $y= x(mod \;m)$

Answer (score 2):

You have a rule that given an element of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, you can write down an element of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.  The problem is that your rule is not *well-defined*.  To be well-defined means that even if you have two different ways to describe the same input, you get the same output.

To be more explicit, observe that in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the elements $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{3}$ are the same object even though they look different (they are defined by different numbers).  Because these are the same element, they should go to the same place under the map $f$.  Unfortunately, $f(\overline{0})=[0]$ and $f(\overline{3})=[3]$ and $[0]\not=[3]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.  Therefore $f$ can't be a function!

The formal definition of *well-defined* is:

- "If $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$."  (Technically, this is not a good definition because writing $f(\cdot)$ implies that $f$ is a function).

If we write functions in terms of relations, *well-defined* can be expressed as

- "If $(a,b),(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$.

Comment: That is pretty much what I gathered from @Jendrik, but it is good that you confirmed what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z_3 = \{\overline{0},\overline{1}, \overline{3}\}$

where $\overline{0} = \{....,0,3,6,9....\}$

$\overline{1} = \{.....,1,4,7,10.....\}$

$\overline{2} = \{......,2,5,8,11....\}$

$\overline{3} = \overline{0}; \overline{4} = \overline{1};\overline{5} = \overline{2}$.

So if $f$ is well defined it'd have to be that  $f(\overline {0}) = [0]$ and $f(\overline{0}) = f(\overline{3}) = [3]$ so $[0] = [3]$.

But $\mathbb 6 = \{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]\}$

where $[0] = \{....0,6,12,18\}$

and $[1] = \{.....,1,7,13, 19\}$

etc.

Note $[0] = \{....0,6,12...\} \ne \{.....3,9,15...\} = [3]$.  But $\overline{0} = \overline{3}$

So $f(\overline{0}= [0]$ if we  write $\overline{0}$ as $\overline{0}$.  But $f(\overline{0} = [3]$ if we write $\overline{0}$ as $\overline{3}$.

So $f$ gives different and unequal output for different ways we interpret equal input.  So $f$ is poorly defined as it doesn't consistantly give equal output for equal input.

Answer (score 1):

In your consideration of the equivalence classes of $0$, you looked at the classes in both $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but for the rest you only looked at the classes in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. If you look at both, the answer will become clear: in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{3}$ are both $\{\ldots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \ldots\}$. So this single equivalence class is getting sent to both $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, which are different things in $\mathbb{Z}_6$!

Answer (score 1):

A function $f : \mathbb{Z}_3 \to X$ is just a function $\tilde f: \mathbb{Z} \to X$ making the following diagram commute:
\begin{matrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{\tilde f} & X \\
\downarrow & & \parallel \\
\mathbb{Z}_3 & \xrightarrow{f} & X
\end{matrix}
where the left map is the projection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_3$. Explicitly, a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_3 \to X$ is equivalent to a function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to X$ with $\tilde f(x + 3n) = \tilde f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_3 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and all $3n\in 3\mathbb{Z}$. In this particular problem, you're trying to take $\tilde f$ to be the projection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_6$, which does not satisfy $\tilde f(x) = \tilde f(x + 3)$.

Answer (score -2):

It is an onto relation from a set of lesser cardinality to a set of larger cardinality. Thus it cannot be a function (by the definition of cardinality).

Comment: That is not a _thorough_ explanation.

Comment: @Leucippus Actually this does answer the uestion "So my main question for this problem is how to find out if this question is not a function".

Comment: @hardmath It is not a red herring at all. You cannot have an onto function from a lesser set to a greater set (in cardinality).

Comment: Even if you justified the assertion of "an onto relation", it would be at best indirect evidence of what actually is not well-defined in the problem's setup.  The OP asks *specifcally* for an explanation of what is not well-defined about the proposed "function".  I'm sure you see in your one-line answer a certain amount of "depth", but it will be lost on most of your Readers.  Please improve it.